cmake variable reference expansion rules
I am confused about variable referencing etc.
It seems when calling a function I create, sometimes I need to use: $foo, ${foo}, or "$foo" or "${foo}" and I get different results, sometimes "$foo" is fully expanded sometimes not.
Where can I find detail about this? I find it totally confusing.

"Where can I find detail about this?" - As usual, you could find details in the documentation. As you can find there, only ${foo} (or "${foo}") syntax can be used for expand a CMake variable. Syntax $foo cannot be used for that purposes.
